# AngularJS model not updating while typing

Tags: angularjs

In the following AngularJS code, when you type stuff into the input field, I was expecting the div below the input to update with what is typed in, but it doesn't. Any reason why?:

html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="city" placeholder="Enter a city"  />
    <div ng-sparkline ng-model="city" ></div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('ngSparkline', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^ngModel',
        template: '<div class="sparkline"><h4>Weather for {{ngModel}}</h4></div>'
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidDev/vT6tQ/12/

Comment: Your directive isn't changing the value of the `ngModel` there for you don't need to set `ng-model="city"` on your directive, I'd look at @drew_w 's example below and set the `ng-sparkline` attribute with the value of `city`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ngModel to the scope as mentioned below -

```
app.directive('ngSparkline', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="sparkline"><h4>Weather for {{ngModel}}</h4></div>'
    }
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q38nF/)

Comment: I copied the tutorial code from http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html and the sample I copied it from didn't have the scope parameter added although the sample following it did. I read what they posted about why scope is required but it doesn't make sense. Can you explain why it's needed in order for the typed text to show? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
template: '<div class="sparkline"><h4>Weather for {{city}}</h4></div>'
```

since you are binding the model to city

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vT6tQ/13/)

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue with this code is you aren't sharing "ngModel" with the directive (which creates a new scope). That said, this could be easier to read by using the attributes and link  function. Making these changes I ended up with:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-sparkline="city" ></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
app.directive('ngSparkline', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var newElement = '<div class="sparkline"><h4>Weather for {{' + attrs.ngSparkline + '}}</h4></div>';
            element.append(angular.element($compile(newElement)(scope)));
        }
    }
});
```

Using this pattern you can include any dynamic html or angular code you want in your directive and it will be compiled with the `$compile` service. That means you don't need to use the `scope` property - variables are inherited "automatically"!

Hope that helps!

**See the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8RVYD/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
template: '<div class="sparkline"><h4>Weather for {{city}}</h4></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that require option means that ngSparkline directive expects ngModel directive controller as its link function 4th parameter. your directive can be modified like this:

```
app.directive('ngSparkline', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^ngModel',
        template: '<div class="sparkline"><h4>Weather for {{someModel}}</h4></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            controller.$render = function() {
                scope.someModel = controller.$viewValue;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but this creates someModel variable in scope. that I think isn't necessary for this use case.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vT6tQ/19/)